# Show and Hide Columns menu in table

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm building a table with large number of columns which I want to be able to show and hide from user menu.

nice example from kendoui site [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/column-menu.html)

My problem is that show/hide menu is the same for all columns, but it is buried deep inside column menu of each individual column.

I want to have that menu only in one place, possibly in table toolbar or exposed in footer so the user does not need to click through the complex dropdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a little trickier and will require some programming.

The solution is based on:

1. Define in the toolbar a checkbox for each of the columns, for this I'm going to use a template.
2. For each of the checkboxes we define a handler that will show/hide the column depending on the current state.

Template definition

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<script type="text/kendoui" id="template">
    <div>
        <label for='field-#= item.field #'>
            #= item.title ? item.title : item.field #
            <input type='checkbox' id='field-#= item.field #' checked onclick='hideColumn("#=idx#")'>
        </label>
    </div>
</script>
```

Now, in the grid definition we define that the toolbar is the result of executing a function:

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->
toolbar   : toolbarGenerator,
```

and `tootbarGeneration` is:

```
function toolbarGenerator() {
    var template = kendo.template($("#template").html());
    var toolbar = "";
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    $.each(grid.columns, function (idx, item) {
        toolbar += template({ idx : idx, item : item });
    });
    return toolbar;
}
```

That iterates through all the columns applying the template for generating the toolbar.

The event handler for changes in the checkbox is:

```
function hideColumn(col) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid.columns[col].hidden) {
        grid.showColumn(+col);
    } else {
        grid.hideColumn(+col);
    }
}
```

And the JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/GerEN/1/

Comment: Sweet, :) after going through the kendo documentation I was thinking that something like this is going to be the right way. Big thanks you've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @OnaBai that's exactly what I meant, except the multiselect widget.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to combine the toolbar example with the [multiselect](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/index.html), by getting the available columns from the grid's columns property.